# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' - for multidex app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I am getting this error while running/building the APK of my application.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:linkedin-sdk:preBuild
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:preReleaseBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:linkedin-sdk:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild
:linkedin-sdk:compileLint
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:linkedin-sdk:checkReleaseManifest
:linkedin-sdk:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
:linkedin-sdk:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:prepareReleaseDependencies
:linkedin-sdk:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:linkedin-sdk:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:linkedin-sdk:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAppyvetMaterialrangebar13Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk470Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPkmmteViewCircularimageview11Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComShehabicDroppyDroppy0252Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSplitwiseTokenautocomplete202Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComStripeStripeAndroid104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareTlandroidappLinkedinSdkUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2 mins 18.454 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I tried almost every solution available on internet but it was of no use. Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.truelancer.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/xml'] } }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.shehabic.droppy:Droppy:0.2.5.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and here is the project level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The linkedIn library also has one gradle file and here it is:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildscript {
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }

}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
          setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 17 
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16 
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations {
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
}
```

Note: My app is Multidex application and I have already extended Multidex class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you guys. Thanks for your concern and all the answers above. I solved it myself by adding in my gradle file.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Welcome @KonstantinBerkow :) Keep coding.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitPatel

Comment: This was okay untill I added a compile dependency of facebook SDK 4+ to my gradle, now it drops the same limit exceeded error even with 12g heap size.

Answer (score 0):

its because of you are using duplicate dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: Sure. Please see the console log in this file:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26158145/console_log.txt

Comment: Have you figured out any solution yet?

Comment: No changes. I just created few simple activities.

Answer (score 0):

***There is a duplicate dependency in your build.gradle file***

You have added

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

twice in your build file. Remove one of them, clean your project and try rebuilding it. It should work fine.

This usually happens when you have duplicate dependencies added. You can do ***gradle dependencies*** command to see if there exist duplicates, and remove them easily.

Comment: Thanks @4k3R. I tried your suggested solution but didn't worked for me. I also executed that command. but it says 'no configuration' and 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 duplicate dependency :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
```

remove analytics or services one. and also multidex one as you have written it twice